# Swift - Using stride with an Int Array

Tags: swift

I want to add the numbers together and print every 4 elements, however i cannot wrap my head around using the stride function, if i am using the wrong approach please explain a better method

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

func addNumbersByStride(){
    var output = Stride...
    //first output = 1+2+3+4 = 10
    //second output = 5+6+7+8 = 26 and so on
    print(output)
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to be the result? An array of sums (4 elements)? In your case: [(1+2+3+4), (5+6+7+8), (9+10+11+12)]? What about the last one?

Comment: every 4 elements add them up and print them out. i simply wish to understand how to implement the stride function with an array list. The final element is the odd one out so i wanted to see how it would behave since the array has 3 groups of 4 with a remainder of 1, preferably i would like to have the 13th number ignored since it is a remainder.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you would like to use stride ...

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]

let by = 4
let i = stride(from: arr.startIndex, to: arr.endIndex, by: by)
var j = i.makeIterator()
while let n = j.next() {
    let e = min(n.advanced(by: by), arr.endIndex)
    let sum = arr[n..<e].reduce(0, +)
    print("summ of arr[\(n)..<\(e)]", sum)
}
```

prints

```
summ of arr[0..<4] 10
summ of arr[4..<8] 26
summ of arr[8..<12] 42
summ of arr[12..<13] 13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first split the array into chunks, and then add the chunks up:

```
extension Array {
    // split array into chunks of n
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

// add each chunk up:
let results = numbers.chunked(into: 4).map { $0.reduce(0, +) }
```

If you would like to discard the last sum if the length of the original array is not divisible by 4, you can add an if statement like this:

```
let results: [Int]
if numbers.count % 4 != 0 {
    results = Array(numbers.chunked(into: 4).map { $0.reduce(0, +) }.dropLast())
} else {
    results = numbers.chunked(into: 4).map { $0.reduce(0, +) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a basic solution and maybe not so elegant. First calculate and print sum of every group of 4 elements

```
var sum = 0
var count = 0
for n in stride(from: 4, to: numbers.count, by: 4) {
    sum = 0
    for i in n-4..<n {
        sum += numbers[i]
    }
    count = n
    print(sum)
}
```

Then calculate the sum of the remaining elements

```
sum = 0
for n in count..<numbers.count {
   sum += numbers[n]
}
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

```
let from:Int = 0
let to: Int = 10
let by: Int = 3

for value in stride(from: from, to: to, by: by) {
    print(getSum(value))
}

func getSum(_ startPoint: Int) -> [String : Any] {
    let end: Int = startPoint == 0 ? by : startPoint + by > to ? to + 1 : startPoint + by
    let range: Range = startPoint..<end
    return ["array":Array(range), "sum":Array(range).reduce(0, +)]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.